# Horizontally centering two items in CSS?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've tried using `text-align` and `justify-content` but both of them refuse to work. I think I've made a mistake with all the spacings.
Here's the HTML:

```css
.container1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.placeholder {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;    
    background-color: #6D747D;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}

.contents1 {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="contents1">
        <div class="container1">
                <h1>This website is awesome</h1>
                <p>This website has some subtext that goes hear under the main title. It's a smaller font and the color is lower contrast</p>
                <div class="button">Sign up</div>
        </div>

        <div class="image">
           <div class = "placeholder">this is a placeholder for an image</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Please tell what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Put the justify-contents and align-items into class image

```
.container1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.image{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;    
    background-color: #6D747D;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to first add some background-color to better see where each element is and then remove these dumb colors.
For the container which has a **display:flex**, please add

```
width:100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 75%;
    margin: auto;
}

.placeholder {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;    
    background-color: #6D747D;
    width: 75%
    height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
}

.contents1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="contents1">
        <div class="container1">
                <h1 class="center">This website is awesome</h1>
                <p class="center">This website has some subtext that goes hear under the main title. It's a smaller font and the color is lower contrast</p>
                <div class="button">Sign up</div>
        </div>

        <div class="image">
           <div class = "placeholder">this is a placeholder for an image</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Assuming you want to center the container1 div with the image placeholder div, the issue is that your divs don't have an assigned with. Set their width to a percentage less than the parent and then use the CSS property margin: auto. You will also need to apply flex-direction: column to your parent div, contents1

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
}

.placeholder {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;    
    background-color: #6D747D;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
}

.contents1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="contents1">
        <div class="container1">
                <h1 class="center">This website is awesome</h1>
                <p class="center">This website has some subtext that goes hear under the main title. It's a smaller font and the color is lower contrast</p>
                <div class="button">Sign up</div>
        </div>

        <div class="image">
           <div class = "placeholder">this is a placeholder for an image</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).